# How can I create/host SQL databases locally?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, ide, development-environment

Can anyone explain to me, in the simplest possible terms, whether it is possible to create/edit and host a SQL database locally on my PC?
I've so far managed to run PHP locally using XAMPP, but have been at a loss as to how I could implement SQL locally too.

For example, can I download phpmyadmin directly to my PC and use it to implement database features on my website without having to be connected to the internet?

Comment: The **M** in XAMPP is the database server MySQL (or MariaDB) so its already installed on your system, just google for *xampp setup mysql*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. And you don't need to download any other software.

Fire up XAMPP and start the **Apache** and **MySQL** servers then go to your browser and enter http://localhost/phpmyadmin.

Once your MySQL server is up, you can easily access it from applications running locally with the necessary configuration (i.e host, username, password, port etc).